# Not able to setup up a quick test for braintree example

Tags: braintree

We tried to setup a monthly subscription plan, using braintree.

We look at https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v3

I download the following code snippet, and save it as a local HTML file in my machine. (I know I need to use a backend server, to generate token and the below HTML code snippet for client browser. I just want to do a quick test without setuping the server first.)

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.12.0/js/dropin.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="dropin-container"></div>
  <button id="submit-button">Request payment method</button>
  <script>
    var button = document.querySelector('#submit-button');

    braintree.dropin.create({
      authorization: 'CLIENT_TOKEN_FROM_SERVER',
      container: '#dropin-container'
    }, function (createErr, instance) {
      button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
          // Submit payload.nonce to your server
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

We click on the button. `instance.requestPaymentMethod` is being executed.

I expect client browser will start to communicate with braintree server, as issulrated as step 3. But it doesn't.

[image]

May I know is there any step I had missed out?

Comment: Are you passing anything into the client authorization, such as a [client token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/authorization/client-token) or [tokenization key](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/authorization/tokenization-key/javascript/v3)? Are you getting anything if you log the value of the `payload` or `payload.nonce`?

Comment: @David Hi, we manage to get it partially work, which I will later post as answer. A quick question, how can I find out, what methods are available in the result object for the following operation `result = gateway.payment_method.create` (Python) ? We can hardly find a good document, to describe result returned from API documentation. This (https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/payment-method/python) doesn't help. This (https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/result-objects/python) doesn't help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup proper backend server, in order to get front end code work. As, without a correct `client_token` (Generated from backend server), front end code will not work.

Front end code will not give any sort of warning regarding incorrect `client_token`.

**Note, you will have a difficult time to setup backend server, as Braintree documentation is poorly written**

After spending 2 days straight, I post my code snippet, regarding monthly recurring billing.

### views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
import braintree
import json
from django.shortcuts import redirect

from pprint import pprint

gateway = braintree.BraintreeGateway(
    braintree.Configuration(
        braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
        merchant_id="???",
        public_key="???",
        private_key="???"
    )
)

class PaymentMethodView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'payment_method.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):        
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(PaymentMethodView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        subscribe = self.request.GET.get('subscribe')

        client_token = gateway.client_token.generate()     

        context['client_token_from_server'] = client_token
        return context


class SubscribeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'subscribe.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(SubscribeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        payload_nonce = self.request.GET.get('payload_nonce')

        user = self.request.user

        result = gateway.customer.create({
            "email": user.email,
            "id": str(user.id),
            "payment_method_nonce": payload_nonce
        })

        if result.is_success:
            customer_id = result.customer.id

            payment_method_token = result.customer.payment_methods[0].token

            result = gateway.subscription.create({
                "payment_method_token": payment_method_token,
                "plan_id": "individual",
            })
        else:
            result = gateway.payment_method.create({
                "customer_id": str(user.id),
                "payment_method_nonce": payload_nonce
            })

            #pprint(vars(result))

            payment_method_token = result.payment_method.token

            result = gateway.subscription.create({
                "payment_method_token": payment_method_token,
                "plan_id": "individual",
            })

        context['is_success'] = result.is_success

        if result.is_success:
            print('success')
        else:
            for error in result.errors.deep_errors:
                print(error.attribute)
                print(error.code)
                print(error.message)

        return context
```

### payment_method.html

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.12.0/js/dropin.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="dropin-container"></div>
  <button id="submit-button">Request payment method</button>
  <script>
    var button = document.querySelector('#submit-button');

    braintree.dropin.create({
      authorization: '{{ client_token_from_server }}',
      container: '#dropin-container'
    }, function (createErr, instance) {
      button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
          // Submit payload.nonce to your server
          url = '{% url 'subscribe' %}' + '?payload_nonce=' + payload.nonce;
          window.location.replace(url);
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

---

### Side note

1. Different API calls, will yield different `Result` object but with different attributes. How do I know I need to call `payment_method_token = result.payment_method.token` to retrieve payment_method_token. No way you can tell by reading documentation. You need to perform debug on the result object, by using `pprint(vars(result))`. **I will be very happy, if someone from Braintree can let me know, how can I lookup for such information, by reading documentation.**
2. The naming is poor and confusing. For instance, **Merchant Account** and **Merchant Account Id** are 2 different things.